# Bash: multiple redirection

Tags: linux, bash

Early in a script, I see this:

```
exec 3>&2
```

And later:

```
{ $app $conf_file &>$app_log_file & } 1>&3 2>&1
```

My understanding of this looks something like this:

- Create fd `3`
- Redirect fd `3` output to `stderr`
- (Upon app execution) redirect `stdout` to fd `3`, then redirect `stderr` to `stdout`

Isn't that some kind of circular madness? `3`>`stderr`>`stdout`>`3`>etc?

I'm especially concerned as to the intention/implications of this line because I'd like to start running some apps using this script with `valgrind`. I'd like to see `valgrind`'s output interspersed with the app's log statements, so I'm hoping that the default output of `stderr` is captured by the confusing line above. However, in some of the crashes that have led me to wanting to use `valgrind`, I've seen glibc errors outputted straight to the terminal, rather than captured in the app's log file.

So, the question(s): What does that execution line do, exactly? Does it capture `stderr`? If so, why do I see glibc output on the command line when an app crashes? If not, how should I change it to accomplish this goal?

Comment: This question would be ideal for Unix&Linux stackexchange, BTW.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misread the `3>&2` syntax. It means open fd 3 and make it a duplicate of fd 2. See [Duplicating File Descriptors](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Duplicating-File-Descriptors).

In the same way `2>&1` does *not* mean make fd 2 point to the location of fd 1 it means re-open fd 2 as a duplicate of fd 1 (mostly the same net effect but different semantics).

Also remember that all redirections occur as they happen and that there are no "pointers" here. So `2>&1 1>/dev/null` does **not** redirect standard error to `/dev/null` it leaves standard error attached to wherever standard output *had been attached to* (probably the terminal).

So the code in question does this:

1. Open fd 3 as a duplicate of fd 2
2. Re-open fd 1 as a duplicate of fd 3
3. Re-open fd 2 as a duplicate of fd 1

Effectively those lines send everything to standard error (or wherever fd 2 was attached when the initial `exec` line ran). If the redirections had been `2>&1 1>&3` then they would have swapped locations. I wonder if that was the original intention of that line since, as written, it is fairly pointless.

Not to mention that with the redirection *inside* the brace list the redirections on the outside of the brace list are fairly useless.

Comment: Without the `&>logfile`, all 3 file descriptors will be redirected to `stderr` for `$app`.  Because `2>&1` happens AFTER `1>&3`.  This is why I just tested it with `sleep` instead of trying to puzzle through someone else's possibly-weird logic.  :)  `2>&1 1>&3` would swap.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hah, true. I wonder if that's an error in the original (that sort of thing happens all the time).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, well let's see what happens in practice:

```
peter@tesla:/tmp/test$ bash -c 'exec 3>&2; { sleep 60m &>logfile & } 1>&3 2>&1'  > stdout 2>stderr
peter@tesla:/tmp/test$ psg sleep
peter    22147  0.0  0.0   7232   836 pts/14   S    15:51   0:00 sleep 60m
peter@tesla:/tmp/test$ ll /proc/22147/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 peter peter 64 Jul  8 15:51 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 peter peter 64 Jul  8 15:51 1 -> /tmp/test/logfile
l-wx------ 1 peter peter 64 Jul  8 15:51 2 -> /tmp/test/logfile
l-wx------ 1 peter peter 64 Jul  8 15:51 3 -> /tmp/test/stderr
```

I'm not sure exactly why the author of your script ended up with that line of code.  Presumably it made sense to them when they wrote it.  The redirections outside the curly braces happen before the redirections inside, so they're both overriden by the `&>logfile`.   Even errors from bash, like `command not found` would end up in the logfile.

You say you see glibc messages on your terminal when the app crashes.  I think your app must be using fd `3` after it starts.  i.e., it was written to be started from a script that opened fd `3` for it, or else it opens `/dev/tty` or something.

BTW, `psg` is a function I define in my `.bashrc`:
`psg(){ ps aux | grep "${@:-$USER}" | grep -v grep; }`
recently updated to:

```
psg(){  local pids=$(pgrep -f "${@:--u$USER}"); [[ $pids ]] && ps u   -p $pids; }
psgw(){ local pids=$(pgrep -f "${@:--u$USER}"); [[ $pids ]] && ps uww -p $pids; }
```

Comment: Unrelated to this answer but use `pgrep` instead of `ps | grep`.

Comment: An error running `$app` will go to standard output I believe. Oh, no it will go to the app log file because of the `&>$app_log_file` I think.

Comment: Thanks for the `pgrep` tip.  I've had `psg` in my bashrc for about 15 years, never bothered to see if there was anything more optimal.  :)

Comment: Yup, just tested by replacing `sleep` with a command that doesn't exist.  The `command not found` error ends up in the logfile, because the innermost redirections happen last.  The OP said some glibc errors show on the terminal when the app crashes, so maybe the app fiddles with fd `3` after it starts.  Its stderr and stdout are both connected to the logfile.

Comment: glibc errors are likely something else and probably bypass even the shell.

Comment: How can they "bypass the shell"?  They're written with Unix `write(2)` system calls to Unix file descriptors.  Unless glibc opens `/dev/tty` on its own, or something, to get a FD for printing error messages, they will go wherever you point `stderr`.  Or maybe the script starts more than just `$app`, and some of the other processes it starts do have their stdout or stderr connected to the terminal.

Comment: Guys, you and your debug techniques rule. I fave this topic for future references!

Answer (score 0):

You need a context first, as in @Peter Cordes example. He provided the context by setting `>stdout` and `2>stderr` first.

I have modified his example a bit.

```
$ bash -c 'exec 3>&2; { sleep 60m & } 1>&3 2>&1'  >stdout 2>stderr
$ ps aux | grep sleep
logan     272163  0.0  0.0   8084   580 pts/2    S    19:22   0:00 sleep 60m
logan     272165  0.0  0.0   8912   712 pts/2    S+   19:23   0:00 grep --color=auto sleep
$ ll /proc/272163/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 logan logan  0 Aug 25 19:23 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 9 logan logan  0 Aug 25 19:23 ../
lr-x------ 1 logan logan 64 Aug 25 19:23 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 logan logan 64 Aug 25 19:23 1 -> /tmp/tmp.Vld71a451u/stderr
l-wx------ 1 logan logan 64 Aug 25 19:23 2 -> /tmp/tmp.Vld71a451u/stderr
l-wx------ 1 logan logan 64 Aug 25 19:23 3 -> /tmp/tmp.Vld71a451u/stderr
```

First, `exec 3>&2` sets fd3 to point to stderr file. Then `1>&3` sets fd1 to point to stderr file also. Lastly, `2>&1` sets fd2 to point to stderr file too! (don't get confused with `stderr` fd2 and in this case stderr just being a random file name)

The reason fd0 is set to /dev/null, I'm guessing, is because the command is run in a non-interactive shell.